# latex article class - bibliography on a separate page

Tags: latex, article, bibliography

I moved from 'report' to 'article' in my latex document, and now I cannot make the bibiography on a separated page ...

I used the commands :

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Le style est mis entre accolades.
\bibliography{biblio.bib} % mon fichier de base de données s'appelle bibli.bib
\newpage
```

But it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally what you did should be enough. However, depending on what is in your article before the *\newpage*, it might not start the new page.

Try this:

```
\clearpage
%... stuff
\clearpage
```

The difference here is, that *\clearpage* definitely starts a new page and breaks any current floating environment, whereas *\newpage* for example only starts a new column in a multi-column environment.